# Web Api Http verbs and method name with a verb convention

Tags: c#

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutHello(int id, string code) {
       // code removed for brevity
    }
```

The above is the amended production code which has the `Post` Http verb but in front of the method name it has a `Put`. I am not sure why the original author wrote it this way which I found it confusing. But this endpoint will be a `Put` http verb instead of `Post` http verb, right?

Comment: I would imagine it would \ should be PUT based on the method name. the code that youve removed. At this time, I can only assume that when this is hitting the db \ or whatever else it should be going to it would be doing an update.  If so then yes, it should be a PUT or a PATCH.  If its creating something then it should be a post.  Also would be worth looking at the response code. Is it sending back a 201 (Created) or a 204 (No Content) this is also an indicator of a POST or a PUT \ PATCH.  However, I suspect its just sending a 200

Comment: It returns Ok with a object. Yes, it is updating something. Just that it has been in the production code for some time.

Comment: The Attribute is the only thing that matter, you can call the method `GetPostPutPatchDeleteHello` if you really want to. Now, why they did it? Two likely explanations: they copy-pasted the method and forgot to rename; they originally went for PUT and had to change to POST for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original author used convention base ApiController where the beginning of the action method's name determines the verb.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations#getting-a-resource
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-controller

However, when setting the verb with an attribute, that convention is overlooked for that method; so for your method it will be a `Post` method.